# EF Core - best way to map to shared lookup table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In my existing db, I have a table to store lookup / picklist values - it is multi purpose, so allows me to store values that might be used to drive multiple combo boxes etc - thing is I am not sure how to model this in EF?

Schema of table is as follows :

PKID int

ValueType   varchar(32)

ValueKey int

ValueTitle varchar(64)

DisplaySequence int

So each ValueType signifies a group of values. I ideally need to grab values from this table when I am displaying data as in my tables I will just for example store a PriorityID value and that maps to a set of values in my picklist table. Where I have seperate entities for things I can happily use .Include etc, but for this scenario I can't see how that can be achieved.

Is there some way to define the subset of records as a separate entity, so I could have Priorities / Categories etc and have it only select the subset of records, or am I going to have to just manually create my queries and filter the records when I join in this picklist table?

Thanks

Edit : I have gone down the TPH route :

```
public class PickList
{
    [Key]
    public int PKID { get; set; }
    [Column("PLValueType")]
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    [Column("PLValueKey")]
    public int ValueKey { get; set; }
    [Column("PLValueTitle")]
    public string ValueTitle { get; set; }
    [Column("PLDisplaySequence")]
    public int DisplaySequence { get; set; }
}
```

Then :

```
public class Priority : PickList
{
}
```

And :

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<PickList>()
      .HasDiscriminator<string>("ValueType")
      .HasValue<Priority>("Priority");
```

However how do I link my Priority entity to my WorkItem entity based on PriorityFlag?

```
public class WorkItem
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkItemID { get; set; }
    public string WorkDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequiredDateTime { get; set; }
    public int PriorityFlag { get; set; }
    public int PriorityIndex { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletionDateTime { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Probably TPH inheritance where `ValueType` is the discriminator.

Comment: could you post the complete table designs and how you plan to drive your lookups from these tables?

Comment: Not sure what else I can add really - that table holds a bunch of records with unique values in the ValueKey field for each set of values in ValueType - it's just a shared lookup table, nothing fancy.

Comment: @GertArnold - looking into the TPH option seems a good way to do it, but how do I rename / map my columns in the inherited class so they then join to my main tables?

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, please update your question with what you've got so far, then we probably see what you mean.

Comment: Now `WorkItem` can have a navigation property `Priority`, where `PriorityFlag` is the foreign key.